# require is not defined in __exportStar(require("./api"), exports);

Tags: javascript, html

`Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });`
that code returns an error: exports is not defined
I found another stackoverflow thread, it can be fixed by putting
`<script> var exports = {}; </script>`
before the
`<script src="index.js"></script>`

But now I encountered require is not defined in this line of code:
`__exportStar(require("./api"), exports);`

is there a way to fix that by using `<script>` ?

I tried
`<script> var require = {}; </script>`

obviously it didn't work

Comment: are you trying to use `require` in a web page with `<script type="module"`

Comment: I want to load this: <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/openai@3.2.1/dist/index.min.js"></script>

it's openai api but it uses require and exports instead of import and export. So I need to somehow define both of them

Comment: Have you read the documentation? `Important note: this library is meant for server-side usage only` - that means NOT in a browser (client)

Comment: Yeah this library is not for browser, I can't find any that is meant for browser, that's why I'm trying to define require

Comment: except that you can't normally run nodejs code in a browser, so, defining require (perhaps [requirejs library](https://requirejs.org/)?) will then just expose the next incompatibility